# C# Automatically Updating Office Customization (installed in outlook)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, outlook, add-in, auto-update

I have an outlook office customization that will not auto-update using the stock publish auto update features included in .net applications. This application is deployed internally (within an organisation) and be deployed and updated from a network share location. The application is compiled in .net 4.0 and we are targeting outlook versions 2007, 2010 and 2013. I have the add-in set up and working however I wanted to test the auto-update feature and it appears to not be working. This is what I get from the installer:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.AddInAlreadyInstalledException: 

The customization cannot be installed because another version is currently installed 
and cannot be upgraded from this location. To install this version of the 
customization, first use Add or Remove Programs to uninstall 
this program: outlookSharePointUpload. 

Then install the new customization from the following location: --removed--
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager
.VerifySolutionCodebaseIsUnchanged(Uri uri, String subscriptionId, Boolean previouslyInstalled)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

The error seems kind of odd to me as obviously it would already be installed...

if anyone can suggest a way of overcoming this... that would be really awesome.

Comment: have you tried the auto update functionality with other computers? Can you rule out that this is one-machine-specific-problem?

Comment: Hi Chris, It appear to be only contained to my development machine. Since posting your comment I have installed it on 5 customer machines and witnessed the auto update doing it thing. So i guess this is just a quirk with my development machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear's to be only contained to my development machine. Since posting your comment I have installed it on 5 customer machines and witnessed the auto update doing it's thing. So i guess this is just a quirk with my development machine